# Rounded Animated Navigation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to reproduce this effect : [CODYHOUSE](http://codyhouse.co/demo/rounded-animated-navigation/index.html#0)

But something more simple.

So I try this to begin. But I didn't manage to expand my circle from the top hand LEFT corner . And I would like that he cover all my page without scrollbar :-/
It's not so simple. After that I would like that my content appears. I didn't manage to do this too :-(

[MY JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/3pn2pkt6/3/)

```
$('.toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');

    $('.circle, #overlay-menu').toggleClass('Opacity');
    $('.circle').addClass('open');

});
```

Comment: First of all your example already has a scroll bar. So overlaying the menu without making the scrollbar bigger is no great feat. Trying to set position height and width in CSS is not going to get you there. You're going to have to get the trigger position and start your transformation from there. Your going to have to get the height and width of the screen and make your overlay large enough to cover it. Set the overlay position to fixed so that it doesn't scroll. You've got a lot of work to do to emulate this. Or you could copy his main.js javascript file and modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There were mostly to do with the CSS instead of the JS codes. Please check the following fiddle once.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pn2pkt6/17/)

```
$('.toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('h4.toggle-menu').text($(this).text() == 'Menu' ? 'Close' : 'Menu');

$('.circle, #overlay-menu').toggleClass('Opacity');
$('.circle').toggleClass('open');

});
```

Comment: I modified your code. It's perfect. Thank you. But I'm trying to add a delay between the animation and my content. I added a delay but nothing happen. http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/3pn2pkt6/19/